# Deploy vuejs application for relative path

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-4

I'm trying to deploy my vuejs application on relative path. I also add the homepage url in the package.json file but it doesn't work for me. How can i do that. Here are the some extra detail which might be easily understandable for you guy's. You can check this details and let me know if its understandable or not i'll try to add some more details.

```
Server- Apache
Url-   "http://example.cpm/subpath/"
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');

// the path(s) that should be cleaned
let pathsToClean = [
    'dist'
]

// the clean options to use
let cleanOptions = {
    root: __dirname,
    verbose: false, // Write logs to console.
    dry: false
}

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

function resolve(dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        // The build folder.
        path: resolveApp('dist'),
        // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
        // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
        // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
        filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
        // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
        publicPath: publicPath
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            Api: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/api/'),
            Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
            Constants: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/'),
            Container: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/container/'),
            Views: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/views/'),
            Helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers/'),
            Themes: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/themes/')
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: false,
        compress: true,
        port: 8080, // port number
        historyApiFallback: true,
        quiet: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                enforce: 'pre',
                include: [resolve('src')],
                options: {
                    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'static/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'media/fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            // we specify a custom UglifyJsPlugin here to get source maps in production
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: false,
                    ecma: 6,
                    mangle: true
                },
                sourceMap: true
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin({
            compilationSuccessInfo: {
                messages: ['You application is running here http://localhost:8080']
            }
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
            favicon: './static/favicon.png'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'static',
            to: 'static'
        }]),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
            chunkFilename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css"
        }),
        //jquery plugin
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello did you have any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> // Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
>   // In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
>
> const publicPath = '/';

Did you try changing the path to `'./'` ?

Comment: So if you build with this setting and then deploy to `/app/subfolder` - the `index.html` is still looking for `app.js` under the root instead of `./static/app.js` ?